# Bash build array in while loop (does not persist)?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

Consider this example, say, `test.sh`:

```bash
cat > test.txt <<'EOF'
test 1
test 2
test 3
EOF

declare -a myarr
declare -p myarr  # "declare: myarr: not found"
myarr=()
declare -p myarr  # "declare -a myarr='()'"
#for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ )); do # ok
sed -n 's!test!TEST!p' test.txt | while read i; do # not preserved ?!
  myarr=("${myarr[@]}" "pass $i")
  declare -p myarr
done
declare -p myarr  # "declare -a myarr='()'" ?!
```

If I uncomment the `for ((...` line, and comment the `sed -n ...` line, then the output of `bash test.sh` is as expected:

```
test.sh: line 8: declare: myarr: not found
declare -a myarr='()'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass 1")'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass 1" [1]="pass 2")'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass 1" [1]="pass 2" [2]="pass 3")'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass 1" [1]="pass 2" [2]="pass 3")'
```

However, if I run the script as posted, then the `myarr` builds in the `while` loop, but once outside, it's empty:

```
test.sh: line 8: declare: myarr: not found
declare -a myarr='()'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass TEST 1")'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass TEST 1" [1]="pass TEST 2")'
declare -a myarr='([0]="pass TEST 1" [1]="pass TEST 2" [2]="pass TEST 3")'
declare -a myarr='()'
```

So, why is `myarr` in this case (in, or rather, after the `while` loop) empty - and how do I get it to preserve its value?

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is that due to use of pipeline, you are forking a subshell and populating entries in your array inside the subshell. Once your loop ends, subshell terminates and all the changes get lost there.

You can use a process substitution to avoid this:

```
myarr=()

while IFS= read  -r line; do
   myarr+=("pass $line")
done < <(sed -n 's!test!TEST!p' test.txt)

# examine the result
declare -p myarr
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a myarr=([0]="pass TEST 1" [1]="pass TEST 2" [2]="pass TEST 3")
```

Comment: Many thanks @anubhava -> that was indeed the issue! Cheers!

Comment: I prefer using other forms such as `exec {fd}< <(sed ...); while read -r -u $fd line; do ...; done; exec {fd}<&-` because it prevents accidentally consuming the same source within the loop, but this is the right way to do it.